# Simple program like ratmenu/9menu that can use images as menu items

Tags: software-recommendation, command-line, menu, scripts

I'd like to be able to select an album by looking through album covers and launch any mp3 player on it or select an image album by scrolling through sample thumbnails and launch any image viewer on it.